# Error: Unable to make rollback because not all files are writable

Tags: error

How to fix this issue, I'm getting this error under var/log/system.log and unable to rollback.

Answer (score 1):

File permissions error or your disk is full.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing this problem but apparently you might be able to rollback the database manually via ssh. Depending on what your OS is the SSH command will vary but i will post the Linux command below and the link for your reference.

Open the same directory the file is in and run this command:

mysql -h servername -u dbusername -p databasename < backupname.sql

Or:

Run this command if you know the full path to the backup file

mysql -h servername -u dbusername -p databasename < /path/to/backupname.sql

The Link below contains more info:
https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/maintenance_ssh_restore

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point, i will update my answer.